# How to extract a single Y variable value using a X variable without using a plot

Tags: r, math, linear-regression

me again!

In one of my assignment I have to create a plot with a regression line in and simply read this plot and give data.
Question: "at 80 degrees F what is the wind-speed?"
By simply looking at the plot you can state its ~9m/s at 80F. This would suffice, but knowing what you can do in R i would like to know for ether future reference and now.

**How does one using only the Data frame ( in picture ) extract a Y value for a given X value using linear regression**
Linear regression because the value itself isn't given, but it can be extracted if you assume its a linear regression.

So in essence instead of reading out the value in the plot ( pic 2 ) I would like to use a function that given a X(temp) value in the DF prints out a Y(wind) value using linear regression.

I tried other stuff i found on stackoverflow, using

```
lm(data~data, dataframe) but that didnt give me the result i desired.
```

[image: head of the dataframe (airquality build in df)]
[image: My created plot to show the regression line]

Comment: this is more of a math question than a programming one. you have to run your linear regression model and then supply the regular linear funktion (y=kx+d) with the results. https://datatofish.com/multiple-linear-regression-in-r/

Comment: Can you include reproducible data? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask; https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look for the `predict` function.

First make a linear regression and then calculate the predicted value with `predict`. Just keep in mind, that you add your X-value in a data.frame.

```
datasets::airquality

lm_air <- lm(Wind ~ Temp, airquality)
predict(lm_air, data.frame(Temp = 80))
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply, Is there a way to just print out the x value without adding this to the data.frame? In essence its just to get a more accurate number from the table over adding it to the df.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you mind rephrasing it?

Comment: Instead of adding the X-value in the data.frame, is it possible to just print out the value? In my case i don't want to use the variable in my data it was just to read the plot and get the exact value from it instead of just looking at the plot and guesstimating.

Comment: I'm still confused, but have two ideas what you might mean. (1)  In the example obove. We want to know what is the expected y-value (Wind) when we have a Temperature of 80 (x-value). The x-value 80 does not have to be part of your original dataset. `predict`won't allow you `predict(lm_air, 80)`. Because the x-value needs to be in a data.frame-format and not just a vector of numerics. Therefore you need  to convert the x-value into a data.frame-format `data.frame(Temp = 80)`. But you don't have to put 80 into your original dataset.

Comment: (2) You want the output to be a single number and not in a data.frame format `as.numeric(predict(lm_air, data.frame(Temp = 80)))`